# How do I determine which assembly is missing in Mono 2.10.2?

Tags: mysql, debugging, mono

I have a web server with MONO 2.10.2 (fast-cgi) on a CentOS 6 box.  Running a plain-vanilla MVC 3 site works great.  However, when I add MySql.Data, it gives me a not-so-helpful error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: The assembly name is invalid.
```

My DLLs are in the right place.  They're referenced properly.  Everything has been done correctly, but Mono still complains that it can't find an assembly without telling me which one.  The problem occurs after simply adding a reference to MySql.Data and without changing any code.  I've looked through the MySql.Data source solution and the references that it needs seem to exist on the web server.

I understand other people have [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516459/how-to-make-mysql-work-with-mono).  I am happy to debug it myself, but I'm new to Mono and I can't figure out how to get a more-detailed error messages.  I've checked [Mono's site](http://www.mono-project.com/Logging_Runtime_Events) for instructions to enable more detailed logging, but their docs assume a certain base knowledge about Mono that I do not have.

Is there a way to get more detailed information when Mono fails to load an assembly?

<sub>I'm not sure if these details matter, but just in case...

-  Mono:  2.10.2 (served via fastcgi-mono-server4)

-  MySql: Connector.Net 6.4.4.0 (from the v4 set in the .Net & Mono download)

-  Webserver:  NGINX 1.0.11

-  OS:  CentOS 6</sub>

Comment: Possibly look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181420/mac-os-x-mono-and-mysql-connector-problem

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks.  There are a number of other questions in the same vein -- it seems Mono 2.10.2 really doesn't like MySql for some reason.  While that is my current problem, my question involves a broader scope: how do I get more useful debug information from Mono?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a "test case" that compiles to an application, try:

```
MONO_LOG_LEVEL="debug" MONO_LOG_MASK="dll" mono my_app.exe
```

Or just temporarily edit your CGI script so that it sets those two variables. Check the logs - you should see what is not loaded propely.

Comment: Thanks.  I know this is a somewhat lame question but do you know where Mono likes to store the logs?  I checked in /var/log and in /opt/Novell/... but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Check your Mono FastCGI configuration file, there's a variable called `MONO_FCGI_LOGFILE` that points to the log file.